# Type '({ items }: PropsWithChildren<TodoProps>) => Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<TodoProps>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm learning Typescript-react and I'm stuck in this error `Type '({ items }: PropsWithChildren<TodoProps>) => Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<TodoProps>'` and I am lost on this.

Complete error:

```
Type '({ items }: PropsWithChildren<TodoProps>) => Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<TodoProps>'.
  Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>': type, props, key
```

Link for code: [sandbox repo](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-vaughan-ys1lt).

Error happens on the declaration of `TodoList` function within the `TodoList.tsx` file.

Any help is appreciated. Cheers!

---

Code:

```
import React from "react";

interface Todo {
  id: number;
  content: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

interface TodoProps {
  items: Todo[];
}

//    v------v here is error
const TodoList: React.FC<TodoProps> = ({ items }) => {
  return items.map((item: Todo) => <div key={item.id}>{item.id}</div>);
};

export default TodoList;
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yeah, the error may sound a bit confusing - in essence it says that you can only return a single `ReactElement` or its equivalent `JSX.Element` in the function component definition, enforced by `React.FC` type.

[React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) [solve](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html) this limitation, so you can write `TodoList` [in the following manner](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=25&ssc=3&pln=21&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOAFQgBMI4BvUuOYVgFxxKAVxAAjWgG4ecNBGpJqQgM4woVAOYze88ABskNQXHEQIhlJRkBfclRp0GzNhAAKOMCq6zgNECpCLOwA2gC6tuTylGou7AAywGpCyOgwAHQAYgDCADzB7p4qAHxwALxwABScfP7eNgCU5aWVsrmpGFlQKJogSjDFsrycfkgB6SAoYJWVoyBBrk1lLUO8cLmswABucADWSACeZSP%206fw2xSdjZ6w2uQD0m1uDa3ANDXa8Dx0Zmd29-UGDRkpGisQKiTUACYUsRfnkCh4IF5ShVqrUxvUlisvi81ldxpNpuj%20HBGs11k89odjudLucHk9ih82vcgVIgA):

```
interface TodoProps {
  items: Todo[];
}

const TodoList: React.FC<TodoProps> = ({ items }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    {items.map((item: Todo) => (
      <div key={item.id}>{item.id}</div>
    ))}
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Short form:

```
const TodoList: React.FC<TodoProps> = ({ items }) => (
  <>
    {items.map(({ id }) => <div key={id}>{id}</div>)}
  </>
);
```

By the way: With pure JS, both class and function components can return  [multiple elements in an array](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings) as render output. Currently, TS has a [type incompatibility](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/82f5b794c1086b1b75a394c32d8d0ca3d1565ac3/types/react/index.d.ts#L557) for returned arrays in function components, so Fragments provide a viable workaround here (in addition to [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)).

Comment: this is why I hate TS

Comment: Sounds like my relationship to the ol' JS Date API (; . Let's be positive and wait for a fix of [#21699](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699) (which also explains historic reasons for above behavior)

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered a similar error.  Eventually I noticed that I'd renamed the file incorrectly from .js to .ts instead of to .tsx when converting a component to a FunctionComponent with TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

I also got this error when I was trying to return `children` props from my `Loading` component like below.

```
    const { loading, children } = props;
    return loading ? <p>Loading ... </p> : children;
```

Then i realize that **React is expecting only one return value(1 parent component) from its `render` method.** Therefore I wrapped *children* props with `React.Fragment` which is denoted by `<></>` and that solves my problem. Below is my `Loading`component sample, hope that helps someone else.

```
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";

interface ILoadingProps {
  loading: boolean;
}
export const Loading: FunctionComponent<ILoadingProps> = (props) => {
  const { loading, children } = props;
  return loading ? <p>Loading ... </p> : <>{children}</>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had allowed a "TypeScript Quick Fix" in VSCode to add async to the main functional component interface.

`const Welcome: React.FC<TProps> = async (props) => {`

After removing it,

`const Welcome: React.FC<TProps> = (props) => {`

things were back to normal.